# takeLatest running multiple times when called from onScroll

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I call an action inside onScroll method of a Box (material ui) but I need the saga to be called only once, but that is not happening. Every time the user scrolls the div, the saga is called multiple times, even when I use `takeLatest`. How can I make the saga to be called only once?

```
function* watchPanelScroll() {
  yield takeLatest(PANEL_SCROLL.scroll, handleScrollPanel)
}

export default watchPanelScroll
```

Is `takeLatest` suppose to work like that? I need to run a saga everytime the user scrolls a div, but i want it to be called only once. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`takeLatest` is not supposed to work like that. Quoting the docs it
`cancels any previous saga task started previously if it's still running.`. So it doesn't matter if the saga was called previously, only if the previous saga is still running. I don't know what you are doing in `handleScrollPanel` but if it is only something synchronous and since the scroll events are asynchronous there will never be anything to cancel.

The actual solution will depend on what you mean by `I need the saga to be called only once`. If you truly want this saga to be called only once then you can use the `take` effect.

```
function* watchPanelScroll() {
  const action = yield take(PANEL_SCROLL.scroll)
  yield call(handleScrollPanel, action)
}
```

But odds are you want to reset the "once" condition after some time. If you want to only limit how often the saga is called by some specific time, something like [throttle](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#throttlems-pattern-saga-args) or [debounce](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api#debouncems-pattern-saga-args) might be useful.

If on the other hand the reset is caused by some specific action (navigation, opening some modal etc.), then you can use another redux action.

```
function* watchPanelScroll() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(PANEL_SCROLL.scroll)
    yield call(handleScrollPanel, action)
    yield take(SCROLL_RESET)
  }
}
```